# How to find installed apllication from control panel using java/groovy?

Tags: java

Currently I am testing API testing for my application using soapui.

I need to verify that build version of my application befor proceeding functional  testcases. Currently i am changing manually everytime when I install new build. Is it possible to get my installed apllication version from control panel using java / groovy?

Comment: Where and how is the version stored?

Comment: I am able to see the version in control panel.. but not sure where they stored

Comment: @ChanGan, can you show the screen shot, how you verify from control panel?